# Automate SQL quote and NewLine

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

Often I will have TSQL from SSMS that I need to use in c# .NET
Adding the " and Environment.NewLine is tedious
Is there a tool / macro to automate this formatting?

TSQL raw

```
select * 
  from hmAdjusted 
 order by [hmAdjusted] desc;
```

TSQL in C# .NET

```
string select = "select * " + Environment.NewLine + 
                "  from hmAdjusted " + Environment.NewLine + 
                " order by [hmAdjusted] desc;";
```

I am not asking for alternate approaches.
I am specifically asking how to automate that specific formatting.
Right or wrong that is how I format my code for this project.

Comment: Thorsten's answer applies. If you *still* want line breaks, `"select * \nfrom hmAdjusted \norder..."` is shorter.

Comment: Either use stored prodedures, or if you need to have the SQL in your code store the statements in the settings class. If you've got more than a handful of statements writing them all out like that (and maintaining them) is going to get dull very quickly

Comment: @LeeWillis So you suggest to open the internal queries for every user to modify?

Comment: @Heinzi I don't want something shorter.  I want the formatting in the question.

Comment: @Heinzi I don't want it to just yield the formatting.  That is literally how I want the formatting in code for readability.

Comment: @Frisbee: Ah, ok, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment from EakTheCat regular expression may be a better way to go
But I already wrote a small stand alone utility
All the tabs look strange but when I paste that is the typical number of tabs that I need to be in

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}" 
        Title="SQL Formatter" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox  AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"  
                      Text="{Binding Path=Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=Output, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.ComponentModel;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string input = "input raw TSQL here";
        public string Input
        {
            set
            {
                if (input == value) return;
                input = value;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("string query = ");
                bool first = true;
                foreach(string line in input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                        continue;
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        sb.AppendLine(" + Environment.NewLine + ");
                    sb.Append("\t\t\t\t\t\t\"" + line + " \"");
                }
                sb.Append(";");
                Output = sb.ToString();
            }
            get { return input; }
        }
        private string output = string.Empty;
        public string Output
        {
            set
            {
                if (output == value) return;
                output = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Output");
            }
            get { return output; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this is all you want to hear: No, there's no out-of-the-box tool in Visual Studio to automate this. Feel free to write your own (addendum: You might succeed fiddling with Visual Studio's *Find & Replace* function).

Comment: Maybe my objective is making stuff more human readable.  I am not looking for alternate approaches.

Comment: Yes it can be automated.  I will write a short program if I need to.

Comment: Maybe I wanted to know if there was an existing tool before I wrote it from scratch.

Comment: If you read it as a yes no question then why the long answer about alternatives?

Comment: As stated in the first I am not looking for alternatives.  If you accept the question as written I specifically ask for that formatting.   Thanks for your input.

Comment: So it does not make sense to you.  That is still the question.

Comment: No I did not ask why you are suggesting alternatives.  I stated I was not looking for alternatives.  I did you give two sentences about what I want.  "I am not asking for alternate approaches. I am specifically asking how to automate that formatting."   You just did not accept my explanation.   Thanks for your feedback and input but it was and is just a simple literal question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @"multiline text" [multiline string in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287596(v=vs.71).aspx) ...

**EDIT** for "I am specifically aksing how to automate that formatting."**:**

Try using "ctrl+shift+h" replace in files. Select copied SQL in editor and do some replaces with find-options.

1. enable regular expressions.
2. replace ^(start of line) with " (start of string) in selection.
3. replace \r?\n with " + Environment.NewLine + \r\n

You'll need to close last line with "; manualy though.

Comment: Thanks.  This is close but it makes the text get left aligned.  For support and readability I want it indented like  the example.

Comment: Check my updates, maybe you'll find something usefull

Comment: I did not even think about regular expressions.  I will give it a try.  Last line manually is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a little bit silly, but I think that's what you need:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var query = "select * from hmAdjusted order by [hmAdjusted] desc;";
        var result = MyQueryFormatter(query);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static string MyQueryFormatter(string query)
    {
        var beforeWhatAddNewLine = new string[] { "from", "order" };
        var temp = query.Split(' ');
        var tempLength = temp.Count();
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempLength; i++)
        {
            if (beforeWhatAddNewLine.Contains(temp[i]))
            {
                result.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else if (i != 0)
            {
                result.Append(" ");
            }
            result.Append(temp[i]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

And result:

[image]

You config your `beforeWhatAddNewLine` collection only once, and then just use it. Also, this can be done via LINQ, let me know, if you want another solution.

Comment: Thanks  See my answer.  I basically went with that approach.  I specifically need to to take multi line input.  The actual queries I am bringing over are massive with CTE, temp, joins, and comments.

Answer (score 0):

How about `string.Join` that lets you keep the formatting

```
            var select = string.Join("\n", "select * ",
                                           "  from hmAdjusted ",
                                           " order by [hmAdjusted] desc;");
```

Comment: It still does not automate the raw TSQL to C# formatted.